# Time series/ ARMA Simulation

Tags: r, arima, simulation, fourier-transform, spectral-analysis

Given: I have a question, given a continuous real spectral density f(w), -infinity

my idea:
I would folding, discretize and truncate the spectral density to get a real (one-sided) discrete spectral density.
Afterwards via the inverse FFT, I would calculate the autocovariance function (acvf) of the desired ARMA (,which i complex-valued), i.e R(t) t=0,...N-1.
Since I know that a  (complex-valued) acvf is hermitian, I can also get R(-t) t=1,...N-1.

Until now am I right? (I am a little confused that the acvf is complex for an (desired) ARMA-TS. is it possible that also the defining polynomial of an ARMA-TS are complex?

If this all is true,  I would apply the extended Yule-walker algorithm, as proposed in Krank & Clausen (On the Calibration of ARMA Processes for Simulation)

THX for any help (concrete steps/ideas are welcome)